# Alternatives to the code below? I am very new to coding

Tags: python-3.x, numbers, number-formatting

```
import math
i = (2)
max = (2048)
num = (2)
while i < max:
    print(int(i))
    i *= num
    if i > max:
        i /= num
        break
if i == max:
    while i <= max:
        print(int(i))
        i /= num
        if i == round(1):
            break
        else:
            print(int(i))
            i /= num
            if i == round(1):
                break
```

I am very new to the coding scene, so I thought a good language to start from is PYTHON3!
For some odd reason, I wanted the program to print out 2 and double it up to 2048. I then wanted to print out the numbers but divided them by 2! I got what I wanted in about 1-2 hours (I know... a complete pleb.)

Since I am very new, I just wanted to see in what ways this can be shortened/improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is good for the most part, it's just verbose. You don't need to wrap variables in parantheses, and you don't need to import math for this. Other than that good job.

```
i = 2
while i < 2048:
    print(i)
    i *= 2
while i > 2:
    i //= 2
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be further improved like this code:
A few pointers to make: 1) use more descriptive variable names, like `upper_bound`, and avoid built-in like `max`; 2) learn the basics like `looping` and variable assignment and expressions, etc.

```
upper_bound = 2048

num = 2

while num < upper_bound:
    num = num * 2

    print(num, end='\t')

    

while num > 0:
    num = num // 2
    print(num, end='\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(1,12):
  z = 2**x 
  print(z)
  
  
for y in range (12,1,-1):
  z = 2**y 
  print(z)
```

Write a function call like below in the console

```
printMultiples(2,2048,2)
```

```
def printMultiples( initialValue,endValue,multipliedBy): 
    initialValueSaved =  initialValue
    while initialValue <= endValue:
        print(initialValue)
        initialValue *= multipliedBy
    
   
    while endValue >= initialValueSaved:
        print(endValue)
        endValue //=multipliedBy
```